# Scale2x utility for Mac OS X?

Tags: png, resize, osx

Is there an already compiled utility for the [Scale2x](http://scale2x.sourceforge.net/) utility for Mac OS X? I've found source code but I'm looking for a utility that is already built.

Comment: This story about a new pixel-to-vector algorithm may be of interest (the source site looks a bit overloaded right now): http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,2845,2385811,00.asp

Comment: Or if you want the "official" site: [http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/pixelart/index.html](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/pixelart/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The source code compile nicely on my Mac with the Darwin configuration file. I use the MacPorts tools to install and maintains the libs. However i was forced to update a line of the source code in the file.c file, due to the changes in the libpng library :

Find the line which makes a function call to:
    png_set_gray_1_2_4_to_8

and replace the call with
        png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8

([Source](http://ajclarkson.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/compiling-ptam-on-osx-leopard/))